# Heatmap using latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, software-recommendations, heat-map

I have a very large dataframe of +10Million rows containing information about route points of vessels in maritime traffic.

[image]

I wanted to create a heatmap to highlight the areas with higher traffic flow using Python but I am kinda lost doing so.

I've tried a few things, but some options just take to long to run or visualization is not very good.

Does anyone know a good way to approach this dataframe. I was thinking of dividing the map in squares and doing a heatmap of the squares. Also it could be interesting to regulate the size of these squares.

If anyone has a recommendation I'm open to it.

i got this using datshader:
[image]

but i wanted to get something like this:
[image]

Comment: If you want to plot the points directly, you could check out [datashader](https://datashader.org/index.html). It's a Python visualization package that can handle hundreds of millions of points. For interactive plots, you can use [datashader via holoviz](https://holoviz.org/tutorial/Plotting.html#datashader).

Comment: Keep in mind that cells of equal size in decimal degrees will vary in area by latitude (as the meridians collapse toward the poles). This will result in distortion if you don't consider area in in your "heat" calculation.

Comment: @AaronZuspan Thanks very useful indeed

Comment: @Vince thanks i will take it into account :)

Comment: @BERA I edited the post, maybe its more clear now

Comment: Could you please share a link to the data source?

Comment: @Ratislaus its in here http://worldroutes.s3.amazonaws.com/routes.csv. 
Its from an article

Comment: I failed to download that file, but I found some similar geojson data. Please, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of [shapely polygons](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.Polygon.html) representing the cells of your coordinate grid, and then count the number of times each route [intersects](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.intersects.html) each polygon. This number should be multiplied with the trip count of each route to get the total number of times ships cross that polygon. An array with those numbers can be shown with [matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) using an appropriate color map:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import shapely as shp
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import numpy as np

# make values for a typical coordinate grid with a specified step
step = 5
lons_full = np.arange(-180, 180 + step, step)
lats_full = np.arange(90, -90 - step, -step) # latitudes range from 90 to -90 to match array row indices growing from top to bottom

# get values for a special grid, representing central points of cells in the normal grid
halfstep = step/2
lons = lons_full[:-1] + halfstep
lats = lats_full[:-1] - halfstep

# make a 2D array to keep square polygons corresponding to those grid cells
squares = [[None for col in range(len(lons))] for row in range(len(lats))]
squares_shape = np.asarray(squares).shape

# make shapely polygons and store them in that array
for row, col in np.ndindex(squares_shape):
    # longitudes correspond to columns, latitudes to rows
    lon = lons[col]
    lat = lats[row]
    # define vertices of a square polygon
    bottom_left = (lon - halfstep, lat - halfstep)
    bottom_right = (lon + halfstep, lat - halfstep)
    top_right = (lon + halfstep, lat + halfstep)
    top_left = (lon - halfstep, lat + halfstep)
    coords = (bottom_left, bottom_right, top_right, top_left, bottom_left)
    # make a polygon
    squares[row][col] = shp.Polygon(coords)

# get ship routes from https://github.com/newzealandpaul/Shipping-Lanes
routes_file = '.\\Shipping-Lanes-main\\data\\Shipping_Lanes_v1.geojson'
routes_gdf = gpd.read_file(routes_file)
print(routes_gdf.head())
# ship routes data frame looks like this:
#   FID  OBJECTID    Type                                           geometry
#0    0         1   Major  MULTILINESTRING ((-34.85760 -8.13738, -34.6743...
#1    1         2  Middle  MULTILINESTRING ((-52.14663 47.21993, -52.0640...
#2    2         3   Minor  MULTILINESTRING ((100.43797 13.33198, 100.4257...

# make a numpy array (of the same shape as that 2D polygon array)
# where each element keeps the number times ships cross the respective polygon
trip_count = np.zeros(squares_shape)
for index, poi in routes_gdf.iterrows():
    # each row is a set of line strings representing routes
    multiline = routes_gdf.loc[index, 'geometry']
    for line in multiline.geoms:
        # count how many times this line intersects polygons
        for row, col in np.ndindex(squares_shape):
            if line.intersects(squares[row][col]):
                # simulate trip counts, up to 3 millions for each line
                trip_count[row, col] = trip_count[row, col] + 1 * np.floor(np.random.rand()*3e6)

# get coastlines and countries
countries_file = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
countries_gdf = gpd.read_file(countries_file)

# show everything on one plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
plt.title('Distribuzione del traffico marittimo globale')
# show coastlines and countries
countries_gdf.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='grey')

# make bounds for 10 sections of a colour bar
cmap = cm.Reds
trips_min = trip_count.min()
trips_max = trip_count.max()
bounds = np.linspace(trips_min, trips_max + 1, 11)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=cmap.N)
# show squares, whose colour represents the trip count
im = ax.imshow(trip_count, cmap=cmap, alpha=0.5, extent=(min(lons_full), max(lons_full), min(lats_full), max(lats_full)), norm=norm)
# add a color bar
cb = fig.colorbar(im)
cb.set_label('Numero di trip_count unici per cella')

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

As you see, the data comes from some other source (since I failed to download your file), and it doesn't contain any trip count values, so I simulated them through some random numbers going up to 3 million, which is close to the trip counts from your CSV data, although these numbers seem to be unrealistically large. Anyway, you should take those values directly from the "trip_count" column of your data frame.